# What type of database is used in large softwares?

Tags: database

I recently made an application in Java FX.  The database used in it was MySQL. When I tried to run my application a system I got some errors because MySQL was not present in that system.

My doubt is that, how large softwares like some games, photoshop, antiviruses or any software that needs a database can be installed and run successfully in any system ? What type of database are they using ?

Comment: **All of them of are used**.  This question seems very broad.  I have to downvote it for that reason.

Comment: Define **large**.

Comment: Often what happens is (1) the application is "light-weight" and it embeds [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/); or (2) the application is non-Enterprise and it installs the database it needs (some hand waiving). For example, you often see [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database.aspx) installed for Windows applications that have heavier needs than a simple embedded database. Some applications have "Enterprise" class needs, and they will require a dedicated SQL server, like Microsoft SQL, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, etc.

Comment: Also see [Native Database Support in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7781922) on Stack Overflow. And here's a search: [java how to persist relational data](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+how+to+persist+relational+data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a full RDMS, then use SQLite.  You will need to load some binaries on to any system you deploy it to, but it is, well, much lighter weight, and does not add any background server processes.

https://sqlite.org/

Comment: I don't asked about my application. I asked about other softwares.

Comment: Many large scale applications eg Firefox, McAfee use SQLite as their storage system.  https://sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html